# Date conversion using SQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to convert the date format from `YYYY-MM-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` using `SQL Server 2008`.  Any hint or sugggestion will be greatly helpful.

Comment: You started only with a date and want the time too?, just the `00:00:00.000`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thanks t this is what I exactly wanted CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-28', 127)
```

Returns `2015-05-28 00:00:00.000`

Use this page as a reference for future conversions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: I want to the 'T' value as well and also the space between yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm:ss is not required.  What does the 'T' mean here. Timezone ?

Comment: If you want the T, use varchar/nvarchar and 126 instead of datetime and 127. `CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)`  T is just a delimiter according to ISO 8601 standards

Comment: Thanks, this is what I exactly wanted CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)

Answer (score 2):

Just cast to `datetime` type:

```
SELECT CAST('2015-05-28' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I exactly wanted CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)